# Meteor Login Service Not Configured

Tags: javascript, cordova, meteor

I'm using Meteor.loginWithFacebook to give users access to my app. The code is

```
Meteor.loginWithFacebook({
    loginStyle:"redirect"
}, function(err){
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    else{
        window.location = "/landing"
    }
});
```

My server has an accounts.js with the following:

```
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.remove({
  service: "facebook"
});
ServiceConfiguration.configurations.insert({
  service: "facebook",
  appId: "id",
  secret: "secret"
});
```

It works on desktop and has worked when bundled into cordova, yet suddenly, it does not work and presents me with the error that Login service not yet configured.

> Uncaught Error: ServiceConfiguration.ConfigError: Login service configuration not yet loaded:2199:http://meteor.local/packages/blaze.js

I keep seeing **Accounts.loginServicesConfigured()** mentioned everywhere but do not see that explained in the docs and thus don't know how to use it.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is in IronRouter:

```
waitOn:function(){
    Accounts.loginServicesConfigured();
}
```

Comment: I'm currently using this for my login page but I can still trigger the error. Any thoughts?

    Router.route('/login', {
        waitOn: function() {
            Accounts.loginServicesConfigured();
        },
    });

Comment: You may have to block it out by using a setTimeout.

waitOn: function(){
    setTimeout(function(){ Accounts.loginServicesConfigured();) },500);
}

Answer (score 1):

Check http://devdocs.io/meteor/ and search for `Accounts.loginServicesConfigured`. I believe you can use it on iron:router `waitOn` function.

Comment: That was not located in devdocs.io and isn't really mentioned in the meteor official docs either. But you lead me in the right direction regardless, I've posted the answer.