# Meteor loginWithApple oauth - "Service not configured"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, oauth, apple-login

I'm adding Apple login, the latest oauth package to join Meteor, but I'm running into the error message *"Service not configured"*. It seems that a lot of the [solutions](https://forums.meteor.com/t/oauth-service-not-configured-error/25037/4) [[another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30007486/meteor-login-service-not-configured)] talk about using `ServiceConfiguration` to fix these errors, but I haven't had to initialize any of the other meteor logins such as `loginWithGoogle` or `loginWithFacebook`. Based on my reading through the github package Meteor.loginWithApple is configured the same way as these existing login functions. What configuration issue might be triggering this?

When I look at `Meteor.settings.private.oAuth`, `apple` is right there alongside `google` and `facebook`.

First, I installed these two https://atmospherejs.com/quave/accounts-apple, https://atmospherejs.com/quave/apple-oauth

```
meteor add quave:accounts-apple
meteor add quave:apple-oauth
```

Then set up the `config` in `settings.json` alongside facebook and google `oauth` per this [guide](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/06/04/what-the-heck-is-sign-in-with-apple).

**settings.json**:

```
"apple": {
  "teamId": "yyexamplexx",
  "clientId": "com.example.client",
  "keyId": "zzexamplewq",
  "secret": "zxcvsdfasdfexamplezlongstrxcvsdfasdf",
  "redirectUri": "https://example.com/apple-redirect"
},
```

**Client**:

```
continueWithApple = () => {
  Meteor.loginWithApple({}, function(err, res) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    //running ok
  });
};

<Form.Button
  id="appleid-signin"
  fluid
  basic
  className="continue apple"
  data-color="black"
  data-border="true"
  data-type="sign in"
  onClick={() => {
    this.continueWithApple();
  }}
>
```

Comment: How do you pass the `"apple"` credentials from `settings.json` to the `ServiceConfiguration`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the config `oauth` settings aren't being passed on, so we had to do something like the following in order to set up the credentials and stop the "Service not configured" error message:

```
Meteor.startup(() => {

  // remove any existing service so you can configure the latest one
  Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.remove({ service: "apple" });
  // setup apple login, drawing from your settings.json
  Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.insert(Meteor.settings.private.oAuth.apple);

...

)}
```

Our configuration looked something like:

```
  "private": {
    "oAuth": {
      "apple": {
        "secret": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nxyzexamplexyz\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----",
        "redirectUri": "https://www.example.com/_oauth/apple",
        "clientId": "com.example.client",
        "teamId": "WXYZ8EXAMPLE",
        "keyId": "456EXAMPLE",
        "scope": "name%20email",
        "responseMode": "form_post",
        "responseType": "code",
        "service": "apple"
      }
```

It seems to be [important](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/oauth/oauth_common.js) that the `redirectUri` ends with `_oauth/apple` since meteor's `loginWithApple` is looking for that. Didn't need to handle the callback at all, the packages below take care of it.

```
meteor add quave:accounts-apple
meteor add quave:apple-oauth
```

Also important to put the `%20` in the scope `name%20email`...it [just worked](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_js/incorporating_sign_in_with_apple_into_other_platforms).

Comment: @Jankapunkt this is how you pass the credentials over